# Difference between 区別 and 差別

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

What is the difference between 区別{くべつ} and 差別{さべつ}?

I looked them up in my Japanese to Chinese dictionary, but the dictionary defines them to be "difference", to put it literally.

Comment: This seems like a question your dictionary should be able to answer for you. What is the difference in meaning between 区 and 差 in Chinese usage?

Comment: 区 by itself would mean "area", but 区別 means "difference".
差 by itself means "difference". The phrases mean the same, but the words by themselves are different.

Comment: 区別 is to distinguish between two areas - i.e. two things belong in different categories. 差別 is to distinguish between two levels. Or to say there is a 差 between two things. That's why the latter means discrimination (as in sexual discrimination 性差別)

Comment: I see. Does 差別 always have a negative connotation, then?

Comment: This question is receiving a bit of negative feedback in votes. You might want to add to your question that explains a little bit more why you're confused, where the ambiguity is, where you've looked so far to find the answer, etc.

Comment: Does 差別 always have a negative connotation>> Not always. eg: 差別化をはかる

Comment: To ssb, that was basically my confusion, though. Because they mean the same in Chinese, I'm confused about the Japanese equivalent. To Snailboat, My Japanese to Chinese dictionary defines them to be the same. To Choko, I see! Thanks! By the way...what do I do if the comments answered my question?

Comment: Ideally one of the people who helped to answer the question will turn it into an answer because [Comments are not for Answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers?cb=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

区別 and 差別 both carry a mean of "discrimination" but have distinct meanings in Japanese.

区別 is for putting things in different categories or domains, i.e. the ability to distinguish. For instance, the phrase  [善悪]{ぜんあく}の区別 = to discriminate between good and evil.

差別 often means discrimination in the pejorative, i.e. to place a [差]{さ}, here meaning difference in level or quality between two things, people, countries, etc. Thus, [性差別]{せいさべつ} and [人種差別]{じんしゅさべつ} are sexual and racial discrimination. There are a lot of other words in that category as well. But as Choko points out [差別化]{さべつか} means "product differentiation," so the word is not exclusively used with this meaning.